# open a file in netbeans

Tags: java, macos, file, netbeans

I use this method in opening files, but when i opened my project it won't run because its from a mac device. where do i store the txt file and what should i write instead of

```
(new File("D:\\description.txt"));
```

the method

```
 Scanner inStream = null;
    try {
  inStream = new Scanner(new File("D:\\description.txt"));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("Erorr openenig the file");
}

while (inStream.hasNextLine ()) {
    String line = inStream.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: First, you should avoid using absolute paths, for the reason you are now having. Second, you should store the file relative to the location that the program is executed, then you could use `new File("description.txt")` instead

Comment: in the same package of the project ?

Comment: No, the same location of the Jar OR the parent directory if above that start of your package structure.  If you include the `.txt` file within the package along with the class, it becomes an embedded resource, which will need to be loaded differently and may make the file un-writable...

Comment: Can you please change your title so it is more generic? The problem is not specific to just NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of approaches you can use individually, or combine:

Hard-Coding elements that should be probably left configurable. Making the path configurable, means you can have something different depending on the platform you are on.

If the file is something that belongs *with* the distribution, make sure it is stored at the Class Path, and access it using `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/description.txt")`; where YourClass is a class in your distribution. resource is a path relative to the location of the class (YourClass), so if you want it at the root of the Class Path, you will need to prefix with a forward slash "/". Here, you do not need to worry about OS conventions (forward vs backward slash). As remarked by someone else, you probably should not consider your file writable in that case.

Another typical approach, for storing things that are configuration, but specific to one user, is to store it at a default path location that get's automatically resolved. A good example is the [Java System Property "user.home"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). In the case of a windows environment, it would resolve to the %HOME% environment variable (something like `/User/myuserid`).